# Need Understanding of Laravel Core Feature

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner starting out in laravel 5.2 and I think these concepts below should be explained more straight forward than just reading documentation.

- Service Providers
- Service Container
- Contracts
- Facades

I think a good explanation and examples that can really help beginners understand how these 4 concepts fit together in the framework.

Comment: Watch this series at Laracasts, and consider buying Jeffrey lunch! Jeffrey Way is your best resource to learning laravel.. (This series is free) https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

Comment: This is not an answer mate, but since you are a beginner you better take it step by step, anyway  i like this question! because  i know how to use this stuff but  i dont know what they are and how they work, jeffrey does a good work, check the laracasts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Service provider :**
The so called service providers are the heartbeat of your Laravel application. They are the central element of the initialization process where all the relevant and required code is loaded by PHP. This includes all the essentials from the framework itself, but also any own and custom code you need to load.

**Inversion of Control, or IoC :** 
Can't be explained easly (i only have few ideas about this im not a pro)

**Facades :**

The Facade pattern is a software design pattern which is often used in object oriented programming. A facade is, in fact, a class wrapping a complex library to provide a simpler and more readable interface to it. The Facade pattern can also be used to provide a unified and well-designed API to a group of complex and poorly designed APIs.

[image]
A Laravel facade is a class which provides a static-like interface to services inside the container. These facades, according to the documentation, serve as a proxy for accessing the underlying implementation of the container’s services.

**[MORE](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/)**

**Contracts :**
[LARACASTS FREE VIDEO](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/7)

I know this is not enough! what you are asking is complicated stuff a single answer can't be enough

Comment: Yes. This is not enough but you have given a good startup for him.

Comment: yea i think understanding those things is essential ! people have to understand what they are using

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so first I agree with the others that laracasts is an amazing resource, that will really go into greater detail and break things down very simply.

That being said, the brief overview is as follows:

**Service Container** (IoC container) is a laravel core process that allows you to load objects with their dependencies gracefully. For example, If I have a controller method like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    ...
}
```

IoC container is smart enough to resolve the Request and load up all the dependencies associated with the Request class to make sure it gets instantiated properly.

It also allows you to instantiate classes without having to fully pass along all the dependencies as follows:

```
class ProductRepo(Product $product)
{
    public function get($id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can reference this class without loading it with dependency injection as follows: (make sure to pass in full namespace)

```
app('App\ProductRepo')->get($id);
```

This allows me to not have to pass in a Product Object, Laravel is smart enough to resolve the Product object because the IoC container is doing the magic behind the scenes.

**Service Providers** are a place for you to lace in custom behavior when booting up or instantiating a class. For example, Laravel by default uses a class called the EventServiceProvider. This class's job is to configure the Event system in Laravel to make sure to include all the custom event listeners you create. So if I wanted to make sure that when the EventDispatcher is being loaded up, it brings in all the necessary dependencies.

**Contracts** are really simple. They are just an allusion to php object oriented concept of Interfaces. This concept states that there are classes that establish rules. For Example:

```
interface SearchableInterface
{
    public function search($data);
}

class BinarySearch implements SearchableInterface
{
    public function search($data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This states that any class that implements the SearchableInterface, must have a function search that accepts one parameter. This creates a 'contract' that any classes that implement the SearchableInterface will have to have this function, or the application will throw an error.

This is great for using interchangeable pieces (siblings) and not having to worry that the class is missing a function you need.

Last but not least is the **Facade**. I love facades. In a nutshell all this is doing is creating a static representation of a class that was not defined statically. So lets say I have a class that will get a document from S3.

```
class S3 
{
    public function get($file)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Without a facade you would first have to instantiate and then call get on the class in order to get something from S3.

```
$s3 = new S3;
$s3->get('myAwesomeFile');
```

Laravel allows you to easily register Facades so that you can just use this statically for readability and convenience.

```
S3::get('MyAwesomeFile');
```

All of this has been an over-simplification of each concept, but goes into some detail about some of the basics of each concept. Hope this helps!